# How do I upload a file to an SFTP server in C# (.NET)?

Tags: c#, .net, sftp

Does a free .NET library exist with which I can upload a file to a SFTP (SSH FTP) server, which throws exceptions on problems with the upload and allows the monitoring of its progress?

Comment: **Edit: this answer is from a long time ago and is no longer valid. See comments** You may want to take a look a [SharpSSH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpssh). It supports SFTP out of the box and it's OpenSource.

Comment: see also the questions [SFTP Libraries for .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530330/sftp-libraries-for-net) and [FTP/SFTP module for .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731967/ftp-sftp-module-for-net)

Comment: Another alternative is Renci SSH.NET.

Answer (score 42):

Maybe you can script/control [winscp](http://winscp.net/)?

**Update:**  winscp now has [a .NET library](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) available as a [nuget package](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#nuget) that supports SFTP, SCP, and FTPS

Comment: Good point. I found a guide to doing exactly that: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_dotnet

Comment: The [latest version](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) now even has native .NET support!

Comment: @RonnieOverby, do you mean that WinSCP native .net version has this bug with absolute path?

Answer (score 8):

Following code shows how to upload a file to a SFTP server using our [Rebex SFTP](http://www.rebex.net/sftp.net/) component.

```
// create client, connect and log in 
Sftp client = new Sftp();
client.Connect(hostname);
client.Login(username, password);

// upload the 'test.zip' file to the current directory at the server 
client.PutFile(@"c:\data\test.zip", "test.zip");

client.Disconnect();
```

You can write a complete communication log to a file using a LogWriter property as follows. Examples output (from FTP component but the SFTP output is similar) can be found [here](http://forum.rebex.net/questions/242/getlist-throws-an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-your-h).

```
client.LogWriter = new Rebex.FileLogWriter(
   @"c:\temp\log.txt", Rebex.LogLevel.Debug);
```

or intercept the communication using events as follows:

```
Sftp client = new Sftp();
client.CommandSent += new SftpCommandSentEventHandler(client_CommandSent);
client.ResponseRead += new SftpResponseReadEventHandler(client_ResponseRead);
client.Connect("sftp.example.org");

//... 
private void client_CommandSent(object sender, SftpCommandSentEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Command: {0}", e.Command);
}

private void client_ResponseRead(object sender, SftpResponseReadEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Response: {0}", e.Response);
}
```

For more info see [tutorial](http://www.rebex.net/sftp.net/tutorial-sftp.aspx) or [download](http://www.rebex.net/sftp.net/download.aspx) a trial and check [samples](http://www.rebex.net/sftp.net/samples.aspx).

Comment: My limited testing of various .NET SFTP clients indicates that this commercial product is good choice.

Comment: I've used the RebEx stuff before also when I needed to use it for an SSIS package.  They have good support and documentation if you are looking to go via a commercial 3rd party route.

Answer (score 2):

There is no solution for this within the .net framework.

http://www.eldos.com/sbb/sftpcompare.php outlines a list of un-free options.

your best free bet is to extend SSH using Granados. http://www.routrek.co.jp/en/product/varaterm/granados.html

Comment: It doesn't look like Granados can be used in production environments: it's outdated and seemingly unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not in the .NET Framework itself.   My wish is that you could integrate with FileZilla, but I don't think it exposes an interface.  They do have scripting I think, but it won't be as clean obviously.

I've used CuteFTP in a project which does SFTP.  It exposes a COM component which I created a .NET wrapper around.  The catch, you'll find, is permissions.  It runs beautifully under the Windows credentials which installed CuteFTP, but running under other credentials requires permissions to be set in DCOM.

Answer (score 0):

For another un-free option try [edtFTPnet/PRO](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnetpro/overview.html). It has comprehensive support for SFTP, and also supports FTPS (and of course FTP) if required.