# .NET Open Source CODE for SFTP?

Tags: .net-2.0, sftp

I googled a lot, and could not find a single open source implementation of SFTP in .NET. All i got is 3rd party component for SFTP. can anyone help me with SFTP implenetation in .NET ?

Comment: More accurate duplicate is http://stackoverflow.com/q/86458/50447

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86458/how-do-i-upload-a-file-to-an-sftp-server-in-c-net#86510) and [shrpssh](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpssh), which was the accepted answer.

Comment: SharpSSH is outdated, buggy, incomplete and not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out Granados

http://www.csharpopensource.net/granados.aspx