# OpenSource .NET library for connecting to SFTP server?

Tags: .net

is there a good library out there to connect to a SFTP server and save/load file to/from there? I tried google, but there is so much so I thought Id ask for recommendations. It will be used in a web app...

Thanks :-)

Comment: See [.NET Open Source CODE for SFTP ?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179569/net-open-source-code-for-sftp) and [How do I upload a file to an SFTP server in C# / .NET?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86458/how-do-i-upload-a-file-to-an-sftp-server-in-c-net#86510).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I upload a file to an SFTP server in C# / .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86458/how-do-i-upload-a-file-to-an-sftp-server-in-c-sharp-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SharpSSH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpssh/)

Comment: SharpSSH does not suport AES + SHA, is outdated.

Answer (score 3):

[WinSCP](http://winscp.net/) is Open Source and has a [.NET library](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) available as a [nuget package](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#nuget) that supports SFTP, SCP, and FTPS

Comment: WinSCP is a wrapper I'm looking for a library. any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Current state of SFTP open source .NET libs is as follows:

### SSH.NET

https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET

Looks promissing, but I have no direct experience with it.

### Sharp SSH (also know as TamirGal SSH)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpssh/

One of the oldests, some StackOverflow users consider it [quite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530330/sftp-libraries-for-net/530380#530380) [unstable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86458/how-do-i-upload-a-file-to-an-sftp-server-in-c-sharp-net/86512#86512).

### Granados SSH

http://granados.sourceforge.net/

Looks abandoned since 2004

Atrribution:
This post is excerpt from [list of SFTP libraries from sftp.net](http://www.sftp.net/client-libraries).

Comment: TamirGAL does not suport AES + SHA what's I'm looking for, is outdated.

Comment: Any Other Suggestions?