# is there SFTP Communications in C#?

Tags: c#, sftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SFTP Libraries for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530330/sftp-libraries-for-net)

is there SFTP Communications in C#?

Comment: Yes, there is[.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852369/is-there-sftp-communications-in-c)

Comment: Given that Google will eventually point here, it's not an unreasonable question. :-)

Comment: yes guys , i googled. i found only open source solutions, i wanted to know if maybe you found (maybe in Framework 4) a c# library that does that... thats what i ment...

Comment: @Rodniko: what's wrong with open source solutions?

Comment: Native? The answer is no I'm afraid.  AFAIK there is no NATIVE C# lib for handling sFTP as sFTP is part of SSH, which is the Linux way of doing remote control.  I guess Microsoft's preferd way of doing secure FTP would be FTPS, FTP over SLL.

Comment: @thkala: That word. I don't think it means what he thinks it means.

Comment: .NET Framework doesn't have built-in SSH or SFTP. You need to use one of third-party ones, such as our SecureBlackbox ( http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-sftp.php )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Rebex we can achieve that, see this blog , here everything is explained clearly http://www.rebex.net/sftp.net/tutorial-sftp.aspx

Comment: Rebex is $395.  Do you know of a free version?

Answer (score 6):

There's a .NET component called [SFTPBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/sftp-net.php) which does exactly that. The feature list seems sufficient to me.

They even have a comparison of various .NET SFTP implementations [here](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/sftpcompare.php).

Answer (score 3):

We used the following when trying to do sFTP transfers: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sharpssh.aspx - What I found is that the trick is to google around for C# SSH implementations, not sFTP directly, as sFTP is a part of SSH and you get less mixed up with other FTP implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Not built-in, as far as I know. There is an SSL Stream class and an FTP class, but I don't think they're wired together. Xceed has a library (http://xceed.com/FTP_NET_Intro.html) that supports FTPS.

Also

http://starksoftftps.codeplex.com/

http://www.rebex.net/kb/secure-ftp.aspx