# SSH File Transfer Protocol (SFTP) using C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there SFTP Communications in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852369/is-there-sftp-communications-in-c)

is it possible to do a FILE upload using C# over SSH tunnel?
if so how? is it supported in .net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use third party resources:

- [Granados SSH Library for .NET](http://www.routrek.co.jp/en/product/varaterm/granados.html)
- [SSH Factory for .NET](http://www.jscape.com/products/components/net/ssh-factory-for-net/)
- [Rebex SFTP for .NET](http://www.rebex.net/sftp.net/tutorial-sftp.aspx)

Comment: I have to connect to a server via ssh and download and upload some files. Which one should I use given that Rebex is not free?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible [is there SFTP Communications in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852369/is-there-sftp-communications-in-c) and there is other useful links also on SO

Answer (score 0):

You need to download a third-party library to be able to do that.

The only Open Source library that I've seen is [Routrek Networks Granados](http://www.routrek.co.jp/en/product/varaterm/granados.html)