# FtpWebRequest: The URI prefix is not recognized (with sftp)

Tags: c#, ftp, uri, webrequest

I am trying to upload a file to an FTP server. The FTP server address is `sftp://xxx.xx.xx.xx:xx`. When I try to make a `FtpWebRequest` with it. It throws a `NotSupportedException` that says:

> The URI prefix is not recognized.

Code:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("sftp://xxx.xx.xx.xx:xx");
```

Comment: sftp is file transfer over SSH, did you mean ftps (FTP with SSL enabled)?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I honestly don't know that. I am testing the server and file uploading using FileZilla and it seems to be working fine there and this is the host address I am using to connect to the server. So are you saying that sftp is not ftp and that is why FtpWebRequest rejects it?

Comment: Yes. FtpWebRequest will only work with FTP(S), not with SFTP which is a completely different protocol. FileZilla can do both.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich can you suggest a solution so I can upload my files using SFTP too please?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530330/sftp-libraries-for-net