# Redirected batch file process output not running

Tags: c#, batch-file, process, console-application

I'm attempting to redirect output from a batch file execution to the main window of our console application.

I'm calling the method to run the process like this:

```
this.runProcess("\\bar\foo\blah\", "myBatch1.bat", "bat");
```

The method being called is as follows:

```
public void runProcess(string aPath,string aName,string aFiletype)
{

  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine("Started: {0}",DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM hh:mm:ss"));
  Console.WriteLine("Will try run this file {0} {1}",aPath,aName);
  Console.WriteLine("File type {0}",aFiletype);

  string stInfoFileName;
  string stInfoArgs;

  if(aFiletype == "bat")
  {
    stInfoFileName = @"cmd.exe";
    stInfoArgs = "//c " + aName;
  }
  else
  { //vbs
    stInfoFileName = @"cscript";
    stInfoArgs = "//B " + aName;
  }

  this.aProcess.StartInfo.FileName = stInfoFileName;
  this.aProcess.StartInfo.Arguments =  stInfoArgs;
  this.aProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @aPath;
  this.aProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
  this.aProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  this.aProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
  this.aProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

  this.aProcess.Start();
  Console.WriteLine("<<<got to here");

  Console.WriteLine(this.aProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
  Console.WriteLine(this.aProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd());

  this.aProcess.WaitForExit(); //<-- Optional if you want program running until your script exit
  this.aProcess.Close();

  Console.WriteLine("Finished: {0}",DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM hh:mm:ss"));
}
```

To try to figure out what is happening I've added extra calls to `WriteLine`.
`"<<<got to here"` gets written to the console then it just hangs and nothing further happens.

Suspect my mistake is something very trivial as my experience with this technology is limited.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have double forward slashes in the strings?  That's probably why `cmd /c` wasn't working, because you're actually sending `cmd //c` which  the command processor won't accept.

Comment: Also, if you want the output of the child process to go to the console, why are you turning redirection on?  If redirection is off, the output should go to the console without needing any extra code to put it there.

Comment: @HarryJohnston ok - unsure where the double slashes have appeared from I will amend both to `"/c "` and `"/B "`. In terms of the output I thought it was directed to the child application window for a batch file as default, so to direct it to a different location redirection needs to be turned on? (...but I'm feeling around in the dark as first time using these methods). Also Harry - the last post in this thread in this code I'm currently using......

Comment: If the parent process has a console, the child process uses the same console by default - in other words, there shouldn't *be* a child window, provided `UseShellExecute` is set to `false`.  (You shouldn't need to set `CreateNoWindow`, either.)

Comment: - the batch file is sending files to an ftp, via a separate client application. I attempted simplifying by commenting out the lines you mentioned and it threw an error. I've updated the code below to my working version. The two lines marked `//<<HJ` caused an error once commented out. If you want to simplify and test to a working version for me I'd be very interested to use it..

Comment: I'm guessing you neglected to also comment out the lines that use `.ErrorDataReceived` and `.OutputDataReceived`, etc.; if I have time, I'll test it myself on Monday.

Comment: @HarryJohnston thanks for the help thus far with this, it is working as is, but any further help to refactor/simplify would be excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the child's output in the existing console, you don't need any redirection.  Just set `UseShellExecute` to false and don't set `CreateNoWindow`.

This code works for me:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        Process aProcess = new Process();

        public void runProcess(string aPath, string aName, string aFiletype)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Started: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM hh:mm:ss"));
            Console.WriteLine("Will try run this file {0} {1}", aPath, aName);
            Console.WriteLine("File type {0}", aFiletype);

            string stInfoFileName;
            string stInfoArgs;

            if (aFiletype == "bat")
            {
                stInfoFileName = "cmd.exe";
                stInfoArgs = "/c " + aPath + aName;
            }
            else
            { //vbs
                stInfoFileName = "cscript";
                stInfoArgs = "/B " + aPath + aName;
            }

            this.aProcess.StartInfo.FileName = stInfoFileName;
            this.aProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = stInfoArgs;
            this.aProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = aPath;
            this.aProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            this.aProcess.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("<<<got to here");

            this.aProcess.WaitForExit(); //<-- Optional if you want program running until your script exit
            this.aProcess.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("Finished: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM hh:mm:ss"));
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().runProcess("c:\\working\\", "test.bat", "bat");
            Console.WriteLine("Exiting");
        }
    }
}
```

I took out the redirection and associated logic, and the line that set `CreateNoWindow`.  I also added `aPath` to the command line so that it would work for UNC paths (paths with no drive letter) since they can't be set as the working directory.

Comment: Thanks Harry. We now have a fully functional Deathstar. Only amendment I made was to change this line `stInfoArgs = "/c " + aPath + aName;` to this `stInfoArgs = String.Format("/c \"{0}{1}\"", @aPath, @aName);` as I have spaces in the UNC pathways for the batch files.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you're using `ReadToEnd()` - that's going to block until the process exits, basically.

This is an exceptionally bad idea when you're redirecting both Standard Output and Error - when the I/O buffer gets full, both of the applications are going to freeze.

Instead, you might want to use asynchronous I/O to read the output (and write it to console as needed - you'll need to make sure the Error and Output don't mess each other up, though). Or just redirect either one of those rather than both.

The easiest way to handle this is by using `ErrorDataReceived` and `OutputDataReceived` events:

```
aProcess.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
aProcess.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);

aProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
aProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();

aProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Apart from actually working, this also means that the output is printed out as it comes, rather than when the process exits.

Comment: Thanks for help: definite improvement. It now prints the "Microsoft 2009..all rights reserved" message to the main console but none of the other ftp messages (what the bat file is processing) are being redirected, and the ftp files are not getting transferred.

Comment: @whytheq Does the script actually work if you just run it in `cmd`?

Comment: it runs fine in `cmd` but I have just found the problem: I will detail in a separate post.

Comment: I am running several processes from the console application some batch and some vbs - do I only need to run the code you've given me just once - reason I ask is that I am encountering  an InvalidOperationException on the line `this.aProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();` details include "an async read operation has already been started on the stream"

Comment: Yeah, only once. It will last as long as the process runs.

Answer (score 0):

I amended the first option after `if(aFiletype == "bat")` and the `bat` files are running ok.

```
public void runProcess(string aPath,string aName,string aFiletype)
{
  aProcess = new Process();

  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine("Started: {0}",DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM hh:mm:ss"));
  Console.WriteLine("Will try run this file {0} {1}",aPath,aName);
  Console.WriteLine("File type {0}",aFiletype);

  string stInfoFileName;
  string stInfoArgs;

  if(aFiletype == "bat")
  {
    stInfoFileName = (@aPath + @aName);
    stInfoArgs = string.Empty;
  }
  else
  { //vbs
    stInfoFileName = @"cscript";
    stInfoArgs = "//B " + aName;
  }

  this.aProcess.StartInfo.FileName = stInfoFileName;
  this.aProcess.StartInfo.Arguments =  stInfoArgs;

  this.aProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @aPath;

  //new 18 june 2015//////
  if(aFiletype == "bat")
  {
    this.aProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    this.aProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    this.aProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;     //<< HJ
    this.aProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;    //<< HJ
  }
  ////////////////////////

  this.aProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal; //.Hidden
  this.aProcess.Start();

  aProcessName = this.aProcess.ProcessName;
  if(aFiletype == "bat")
  {
    this.aProcess.ErrorDataReceived += (s,e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    this.aProcess.OutputDataReceived += (s,e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    this.aProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
    this.aProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
  }

  this.aProcess.WaitForExit();
  this.aProcess.Dispose();

Console.WriteLine("Process {0} closed: {1}", this.aProcessName, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM hh:mm:ss"));
}
```