# Can I use FtpWebRequest class for SFTP transfers

Tags: .net, sftp, ftpwebrequest

Can I use `FtpWebRequest` class for SFTP transfers? I am confused if the answer is a YES or NO because I could not find any MSDN link for the appropriate answer.

If the answer is a NO, can you please point me to the correct MSDN link where it is mentioned officially?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you cannot.

See [`FtpWebRequest` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest):

> Implements a **File Transfer Protocol (FTP)** client.

SFTP is not FTP.

See for example [Difference between FTP/FTPS/SFTP - Configurable connection to any of them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33062787/850848).