# How to move a file from one folder to another folder on a remote server using SharpSsh and C#

Tags: c#, ssh, sftp, sharpssh

How to move a file from one folder to another folder on a remote server using SharpSsh?

I'm trying to move a file that is in a folder on the server to another server folder.

I'm getting:

> ERROR: No se pudo encontrar el archivo '/local/opt/oracle/oradata/UTL_DIR/PEDIMENTOS/pedimento.csv'.
>
> Cannot find file '/local/opt/oracle/oradata/UTL_DIR/PEDIMENTOS/pedimento.csv'

This is my code:

```
Tamir.SharpSsh.Sftp ClientSFTP = new Tamir.SharpSsh.Sftp(pHost, pUserName, pPassword);
try
{
    string FechaActual = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    string pFilePEDIMENTOS = "/local/opt/oracle/oradata/UTL_DIR/PEDIMENTOS/pedimento.csv";
    string pFilePROCESADO = "/local/opt/oracle/oradata/UTL_DIR/PEDIMENTOS/PROCESADO/pedimento" + FechaActual + ".csv";

    //Abre sesion
    ClientSFTP.Connect();
   
    if (ClientSFTP.Connected)
    {
        // ejecutar el comando
        ClientSFTP.Put(pFilePEDIMENTOS, pFilePROCESADO);//SEGUIR INVESTIGANDO
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Error de Conexion con el Servidor Remoto");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    lblError.Text = ex.Message;
}
finally
{
    //cerrar conexion SFTP
    ClientSFTP.Close();
}
```

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: error: No se pudo encontrar el archivo '/local/opt/oracle/oradata/UTL_DIR/PEDIMENTOS/pedimento.csv'.

Comment: Ensure that the file exists in that location and that all permissions for both your local folder and the target folder are set properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, do not use the SharpSSH, it's a dead project.

Use another SFTP implementation. See [SFTP Libraries for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/530330/850848).

---

Anyway, if you have to use it (for a very good reason), use `SftpChannel.rename` method.

You cannot use the `Sftp` class, as it does not expose the method.

See `jsch\examples\Sftp.cs` example. A simplified code is like:

```
Session session=jsch.getSession(pUserName, pHost, 22);
...
session.connect();
...
Channel channel=session.openChannel("sftp");
ChannelSftp c=(ChannelSftp)channel;
...
c.rename(pFilePEDIMENTOS, pFilePROCESADO);
```

The "rename" or "move" are basically the same operations. The `.Put` is for uploading a local file to a remote location.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that Put method which you use is to transfer the file from the local computer (the client) to the remote server. The method is not suitable for moving files on the remote server.

To move files you need to either use the SSH client and issue commands for remote shell to interpret (if you know it's linux, then running "mv" in shell will do the job), or, if you have no SSH access, you can try using a decent SFTP client (such as our SecureBlackbox) which supports "Rename" SFTP command (remote file can be "renamed" this way). Not all servers support this command, though.