# send key like Ctrl+A in ssh with SharpSsh

Tags: c#, ssh, sharpssh

I write a simple code with Tamir.SharpSsh to SSH connect :

```
 SshStream ssh = new SshStream(txt_ip.Text, txt_user.Text, "foo");
 var output = ssh.ReadResponse();
```

After successfuly connect to client, i want to send some key directly to client,
Anyone know how i do that?

Comment: Do not use SharpSsh for new code. It's a dead project (not updated since 2007!)

Comment: do you have any suggestion? Rebex is exist but its not free

Comment: See [SFTP Libraries for .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/q/530330/850848) - Not exactly about SSH, but SFTP runs over SSH, so all SFTP libraries can do SSH naturally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its solve by this code

```
ssh.Write("\u0003");
```

Comment: this code solve the problem ...for example this code send Ctrl+C to Ssh Consol....we can use asscci character to write directly client...