# Upload all files matching wildcard to SFTP

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, sharpssh

I am using Tamir SharpSSH for transferring files from remote to local and vice versa with no issues.

But, when trying to upload multiple XML files via SFTP but I am receiving an error:

> Illegal characters in path.

If I try to upload using the exact file name it transfers the file without any issues.

Every time I try to upload two XML files:

```
KDO_E2D_A21_AA769_20170124_143123.xml
KDO_E2D_A21_AA776_20170130_143010.xml
```

```
string ftpURL = "11.11.11.1";
string userName = "Aaaaaa"; //User Name of the SFTP server
string password = "hah4444"; //Password of the SFTP server
int port = 22; //Port No of the SFTP server (if any)

//The directory in SFTP server where the files will be uploaded
string ftpDirectory = "/home/A21sftp/kadoe/";

//Local directory from where the files will be uploaded 
string localDirectory = "E:\\Zatpark\\*.xml"; 

Sftp Connection = new Sftp(ftpURL, userName, password);
Connection.Connect(port);
Connection.Put(localDirectory, ftpDirectory); 
Connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use Tamir.SharpSSH, it's a dead project. Use some [up to date SSH/SFTP implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/530330/850848).

---

If you switch to library like [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) that does not support wildcards, you have to use the [`Directory.GetFiles` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles) to find files to upload:

```
SftpClient client = new SftpClient("example.com", "username", "password");
client.Connect();

string localDirectory = @"E:\Zatpark upload";
string localPattern = "*.xml";
string ftpDirectory = "/dv/inbound/";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(localDirectory, localPattern);
foreach (string file in files)
{
    using (Stream inputStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
    {
        client.UploadFile(inputStream, ftpDirectory + Path.GetFileName(file));
    }
}
```

---

Or use a library that does support wildcards.

For example with [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) (what is not a pure .NET assembly though), you can do:

```
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
    HostName = "example.com",
    UserName = "username",
    Password = "password",
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-dss ...",
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    session.Open(sessionOptions);
    string ftpDirectory = "/dv/inbound/"; 
    string localDirectory = @"E:\Zatpark upload\*.xml";
    session.PutFiles(localDirectory, ftpDirectory).Check();
}
```

You can have a [code template generated in WinSCP GUI](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

---

To explain, why your code does not work: Check the `ChannelSftp.glob_local` method. Its implementation is strange, if not broken. It basically supports only masks consisting completely of `*` and `?`'s.