# SharpSSH: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found

Tags: c#, iis, ftp, sftp, sharpssh

I'm trying to connect to SFTP server using SharpSSH, and getting exception -

> Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.JSchException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found

My code looks like this:

```
Sftp sftp = null;
sftp = new Sftp("ftp://XX.XXX.XX.XX/", "UserName", "Password");
sftp.Connect();
```

Am I writing server address in wrong format?
What can be the other reason? If DNS issues.. then what are those and how to resolve them?

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not use SharpSSH, it's a dead project. Use some SFTP library that is maintained. See [SFTP Libraries for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/530330/850848).
2. The first argument to the `Sftp` class is called `sftpHost`, so you cannot pass a URL, you have to pass a host name, i.e. only the `XX.XXX.XX.XX`.
3. SharpSSH is SFTP/SSH library, not FTP. If you really need to connect to FTP, you cannot use SharpSSH.
4. The IIS indeed does not support the SFTP. It supports only the FTP (and the FTPS = FTP over TLS/SSL). See [Is IIS SFTP natively supported by Windows?](https://serverfault.com/q/648855/168875)
   For the FTPS/FTPS, use the [`FtpWebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest) from the .NET framework.