# Does .NET Core 2.0 have SFTP client?

Tags: .net, .net-core, sftp, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

Needing to use an SFTP  client and looking to build it in a .NET Core 2.0 application.

I was wondering if SFTP is already part of .NET standard 2.0 or will I need to use a 3rd party library for this, e.g. SSH.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no SFTP client in any current (nor past) version of .NET.

See also [SFTP Libraries for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/530330/850848) and many others.

Answer (score 16):

There are many SFTP clients for .net created over many years: SecureBlackbox, IPWorks SSH, WodSFTP, and Rebex SFTP.
SecureBlackbox provides an sftp solution for at least 12 years.
If you are looking for an open source project, SSH.NET on github (https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) should match your expectations.
It is compatible with .net standard which means it is compatible with .net framework and .net core. Moreover, it is a standalone solution that doesn't have third party dependency.