# SFTP download with .NET CORE 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Is there a way to download a file from a sftp server with .net core 3.1 ?

I found various answers which are all outdated. (for example, ssh.net cannot be found anymore)

How is the current status in this topic?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48432921/does-net-core-2-0-have-sftp-client

Comment: @rene your link is  2 years old, and is about .net core 2.0, not 3.1

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to give some pointers as you didn't include which outdated answers you already saw. SSH.Net is indeed old but that goes back to .Net 2.0 if memory serves well.

Comment: I have found SSH.NET meanwhile, but it is NOT compatible to .net core unfortunately.

Comment: There is a [develop branch of SSH.Net](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) that is [setup to work with .Net Core 3.1](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/issues/355#issuecomment-605509043) but [not yet published](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/issues/636). Unfortunately that project was delayed for a while. Perhaps you could try the develop branch?

Comment: @NetMage **thanks a lot**, I will give it a try! Maybe I can even support the project.

Comment: The new version of SSH.NET 2023.0.0 supports .NET 6/7 and .NET Standard 2.0/2.1.

Answer (score 1):

There is an updated version of SSH.net called Neon.SSh.Net
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Neon.SSH.NET/

works in the same way as the old version from Renci.

```
...
var client = new SftpClient(host,port,username,password);
    client.Connect();
    using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite("c:\\temp\\file.tmp"))
    { 
          _client.DownloadFile(ftpFilePath, fileStream);
    }
...
```

Comment: The new version of SSH.NET 2023.0.0 supports .NET 6/7 and .NET Standard 2.0/2.1, so it is highly recommended to use offical nuget, because it contains also other fixes and improvements.

Answer (score 1):

The new version of SSH.NET 2023.0.0 supports .NET 6/7 and .NET Standard 2.0/2.1, so it is highly recommended to use offical nuget, because it contains also other fixes and improvements.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/SSH.NET/2023.0.0