# How to use SFTP to submit/retrieve batch jobs to mainframe

Tags: c#, mainframe, jcl

I have been making a simple ftp of my JCL after sending `site filetype=jes` with my C# code.
However now I am required to use SFTP to send and receive files.
I found renci.SshNet but it does not have a method to send command.

Can someone please tell me how I can SFTP a JCL to mainframe using C#?
What is the best method to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

SFTP (not to be confused with FTPS) is not supported by .NET out of the box. You have to rely on a 3rd party library. See related question here: [SFTP Libraries for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530330/sftp-libraries-for-net)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It seems FTPS is required here according to the notification I received and not SFTP. Is there a library and a page I can refer to for more information on how to do it?

Comment: As mentioned in the related question you have to find a suitable library for the usage of SSH File Transfer Protocol (SFTP).

Answer (score 0):

The answer for your stated problem is that you need `FTPS` and not `SFTP` to support JES extensions for job submission and retrieval (as well as other z/OS specific capabilities).

Here is an [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31624/An-FTP-secure-client-library-for-C) that goes over the details of FTPS in c#.  Its the same command sequence using the `SITE` command as you used under FTP.

For a comparison of SFTP and FTPS here is some information.

Found this [link](https://share.confex.com/share/116/webprogram/Handout/Session8239/Safe%20and%20secure%20transfers%20with%20z%20OS%20FTP.pdf) about `FTPS` setup on z/OS from Share.  This should get you started.  It seems more practical and applied than going to knowledge center and shows the various options and capabilities.  The original author, Alfred B Christensen, is an IBMer.  The material is from 2011 but is still mostly applicable today.

Here is a comparison of the technologies:

[image]

Here is some more background.

The issue is that [...sftp understands a set of commands subcommands similar to those of ftp.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.foto100/fotz152.htm) according to the linked IBM manual for SFTP.  The `sftp` server implementation provided by IBM does not have the full set of extensions provided by the [FTP Server](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.4.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r4.halz001/ftpcasfiletype.htm)

There are other servers out there with associated clients that can provide the capability.  I'm not endorsing this product but it seems to be popular from google searches I've done [Tectia](https://www.ssh.com/manuals/server-zos-user/64/sftp-site.html)  The default implementation of `sftp server` from IBM does not support the same extensions that `ftp` does.

If you're looking for a seamless transition and need transport security `ftps` is a better option but likely requires configuration on the z/OS system if its not already enabled.

The issue is not simply the client, it is the capability of the `sftp` implementation on z/OS as well.

Answer (score 0):

The native SFTP from IBM does not support all the features of FTP. You will need to use [Co:Z toolkit SFTP](https://dovetail.com/products/sftp.html) from Dovetailed. It's free to use with paid support available.