# Change from C# FtpWebRequest FTP code to SFTP

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, sftp, ftpwebrequest

I would really need some help to change from FTP transfer to SFTP. I added some lines in the comment but I'm new to programming and I don't know for sure what I also need to add to fix this problem. The programme works fine but at the moment you transfer your data via FTP. I read some questions here but for now, I couldn't find the right tipp rewrite the program to SFTP.

```
public class FTP
{
    private System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker bw = null;
    private long filesSize = 0;
    private long uploadSize = 0;
    private const int bufferLength = 2048;

    public FTP()
    {

    }

    public FTP(System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker thread, long allFilesSize)
    {
        bw = thread;
        filesSize = allFilesSize;
    }

    public string ReadUserFile()
    {
        WebClient req = new WebClient();

        req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("", "");

        try
        {
            byte[] newFileData = req.DownloadData(); 
            return System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(newFileData);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void UploadFile(
        string ftpServer, string filePath, string username, string password)
    {
        //Create SFTP request
        //Sftp client = new Sftp();
        //client.Connect(hostname);
        //client.Login(username, password);


        //Create FTP request
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create();
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        request.UsePassive = true;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.KeepAlive = false;

        //Load the file
        //

        //Load the file
        FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(filePath);

        //Upload to Sftp Server
        //client.PutFile();


        //Upload file
        Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
        int count = 0;
        int readBytes = 0;

        do
        {
            readBytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
            count += readBytes;
            if (bw != null)
                bw.ReportProgress(CalculateProgress());
        }
        while (readBytes != 0);

        //Disconnect
        //client.Disconnect();


        stream.Close();
        reqStream.Close();
    }

    private int CalculateProgress()
    {
        uploadSize += bufferLength;

        return (Int32)(uploadSize/(filesSize / 100));
    }

    public void DeleteFile(
        string ftpServer, string filePath, string username, string password)
    {
        //Create SFTP request 
        //Sftp client = new Sftp();
        //client.Connect(hostname);
        //client.Login(username, password);

        //Create FTP request
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create();
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        request.UsePassive = true;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.KeepAlive = false;

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        response.Close();
    }

    public string[] GetFileList(
        string ftpServer, string username, string password)
    {
        string[] fileList;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        FtpWebRequest request;

        try
        {
            request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri());
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

            string line = reader.ReadLine();

            while (line != null)
            {
                if (line.StartsWith("./"))
                    line = line.Substring(2, line.Length - 2);

                result.Append(line);
                result.Append("\n");
                line = reader.ReadLine();
            }

            result.Remove(result.ToString().LastIndexOf('\n'), 1);
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();

            return result.ToString().Split('\n');
        }
        catch
        {
            //Error
            fileList = null;
            return fileList;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no simple way to switch from FTP to SFTP in C#/.NET, if you are currently using .NET `FtpWebRequest` API.

There's no support for SFTP in .NET framework.
You need 3rd party library: [SFTP Libraries for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/530330/850848).

That also means that you basically need to scratch your current code and start from the very beginning. Not a single line in your current code would be useful for SFTP with any 3rd party library, as they have very different API to unusual `FtpWebRequest`.

---

There are libraries that offer an uniform interface to both FTP and SFTP protocols.

For example [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) supports FTP, FTPS, FTPES, SFTP and others (SCP, S3,
WebDAV and WebDAVS) over the same interface.

Though it is not a native .NET assembly. It's rather a thin wrapper over
a console application.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP).*