# How to use sftp in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upload a file to an SFTP server in C# / .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86458/how-do-i-upload-a-file-to-an-sftp-server-in-c-sharp-net)

Does .net support **sftp**?

I can't find any sample online.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly as it's a client for ftps, however it does provide a useful background for ftp related information http://ftps.codeplex.com/

Comment: This is not a duplicate anymore with the old question being closed as not-constructive - although I don't understand why.

Comment: SFTP is not present in .NET. Personally, I am using http://www.componentpro.com/sftp.net/ library.

Answer (score 17):

We have used [SharpSSH](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx) for sftp, it works well and is open source.

Code example:

```
sftp = new Tamir.SharpSsh.Sftp(ipAddress, username, password);
sftp.Connect();
sftp.Get(sourcePath, destinationPath);
sftp.Close();
```

Comment: sftp is not good. first, it doesn't support 64 bit (though, these is a custom on some blog). second , the get file doesn't preserve the original file date

Comment: I highly recommend using http://sshnet.codeplex.com instead of SharpSSH. SharpSSH doesn't seem to be actively maintained anymore and is fairly rough. Because of this, SSH.NET was born.

Comment: Is there any actively maintained SFTP-Client available for .NET? I need an OpenSource Lib that is reliable also under .NET 4.5 and later (according to sshnet.codeplex.com, they only support up to 4.0).

Answer (score 3):

We use successfully the [Rebex components](http://www.rebex.net/) (FTP, S-FTP, FTP-S) for that in our projects. They are commercially, though.

Comment: Rebex stuff really is excellent, and their customer support is top notch. When I had to interface to an FTPS server that did not conform to the current FTPS standard, they created a version of their component that would talk to it at no extra charge.