# How to Connect to SFTP server using PPK file using C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, sftp

I have previously implemented an application that connects to a FTP server and downloads/uploads files. This time i need to create the same kind of application but i have a problem. I don't know how to use the PPK(private key) file to connect to the server.

Application specs:

- **Connect to Server using SFTP and PPK**(no idea how to do this.).
- **Download files from the server and write them locally** (this part i know how to do).

If u need more information u can just write them in the comments.

thanks in advanced.

Comment: You need some third-party SFTP client component for .NET.

Comment: So there is no way to do this by only using .net ?

Comment: You can try WinScp. It is free has a .Net library. [link](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library)

Comment: Multiple duplicates, eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092180/how-to-use-sftp-in-c-sharp