# SSIS FTP task does not work while FileZilla works

Tags: ssis, sftp

I am working on using SSIS FTP task to uploading some files to `sftp://apollo.xxx.xxx.com` automatically.

I can do that successfully by manually specifying sever name, server port, user name and password in FileZilla.

However, when I setup in the FTP connection manager, the connection fails (could be the issue of SFTP?).

I am just wondering if anyone could provide me some tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The native FTP task is just FTP. It does not support sFTP.

As you are not allowed to use third party software, you will be unable to fulfill your request. Based on this question, there does not appear to be a base sftp module in the .NET framework  [How do I upload a file to an SFTP server in C# / .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86458/how-do-i-upload-a-file-to-an-sftp-server-in-c-sharp-net)

Comment: well, its what i'm thinking; however we are not allow to use a third party software. thanks anyway