# How to upload file in server using SFTP through ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sftp

I am using the SharpSsh to transfer the file to server using SFTP through ASP.NET.

Below is my source code. But I am getting the error!

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.IO;
    using Tamir.SharpSsh;
    using Tamir.Streams;

    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fuUploadFile.HasFile)
        {
           string _ftpURL = "ftp://22.00.333.444/"; 
           string _UserName = "admin";     
           string _Password = "admin123";  
           int _Port = 22;                 
           string _ftpDirectory = "/TestFTP";
           string LocalDirectory = 
           Server.MapPath(fuUploadFile.PostedFile.FileName); 
           string FileName = fuUploadFile.FileName;;    

           Sftp oSftp = new Sftp(_ftpURL, _UserName, _Password);
           oSftp.Connect(_Port);
           oSftp.Put(LocalDirectory , _ftpDirectory + "/" + FileName);
           oSftp.Close();
        }
    }
```

When i try to run the code i am getting the following exception please help me how to fix this exeception.

```
    System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found
    at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
    at System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(String hostName)
    at Tamir.SharpSsh.java.net.Socket..ctor(String host, Int32 port)
    at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Util.createSocket(String host, Int32 port, Int32 timeout)
```

Comment: Did you obfuscate that IP? Because if not, it's invalid.

Comment: Also, all the examples I have seen do not have the `ftp://` prefix.

Comment: Why are you putting an underscore in front of all your variables? That doesn't follow normal C# conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sftpHost` argument of `Tamir.SharpSsh.Sftp` constructor takes an IP address or a host name, not a URL. And even if it took a URL, it would be `sftp://`, not `ftp://`.

So it should be:

```
Sftp oSftp = new Sftp("22.00.333.444", _UserName, _Password);
```

But of course `22.00.333.444` is not a valid IP address.

---

*And I strongly discourage you from using SharpSSH. It's a dead project.*

For alternatives, see:

- [How do I upload a file to an SFTP server in C# / .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/86458/850848)
- [SFTP Libraries for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/530330/850848)

Comment: Can you please share the link or suggest what i should use to implement the SFTP?

Comment: Just google for "SFTP .NET". OK, I've done it for you, see my edited answer.