# How do I copy file from windows to Pi board?

Tags: c#, ssh, sftp, windows-forms-designer, scp

I want to copy one file from windows to Pi board via ssh.

I am building a GUI using windows form.

Coming to GUI part I found ssh.net library, I will be using this later. But before that, I want to understand how it works and what SCP command to be used, As a first step, **I want to see how exactly the SCP command works. For this, I want to copy a file from windows using the windows command line to the Pi board via ssh. Now how can I achieve this?**  what is the procedure? I searched the internet but I failed to get proper information.

Note: I know I can achieve this using Filezilla client or putty, but my motto is to build my own GUI.

My GUI requirement: Firstly, I want to establish connection with Pi board and secondly, I want my GUI to browse the file which needs to be copied to Pi board and thirdly, I want to fix the Pi destination folder in the GUI itself(no access to user, backend I fix the destination folder as its unchangeable) and fourthly, when user clicks download button file should get downloaded to the fixed destination folder in the Pi board with progress bar indicator for the completion of file transfer - Need suggestions for achieving this? basically, I want the user to select a particular file from the windows using my GUI and on button click file should get downloaded to the Pi board.

Comment: Why do you want to use SCP? Use SFTP. If you can connect with FileZilla, the device supports SFTP, as FileZilla does not support SCP.

Comment: I won't be using FileZilla, am doing my own GUI for file transfer, as I have to download only 1 file as an when required from my PC to Pi board's fixed location.

Comment: We understand that. I'm asking why do you want to use SCP?

Comment: If there is any other method, I am happy to listen. How about SSH.NET lib what SCP command for copying the file?

Comment: Yes, Use SFTP with SSH.NET. I've wrote that in my very first comment already!

Answer (score 1):

Do not use SCP, use SFTP.

A simple SFTP upload example using SSH.NET:

```
using (var client = new SftpClient(host, username, password))
{
    client.Connect();

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(uploadFile, FileMode.Open))
    {
        client.UploadFile(fileStream, Path.GetFileName(uploadFile));
    }
}
```

---

For other options/libraries, see also:
[How do I upload a file to an SFTP server in C# / .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/86458/850848)

Comment: I was confused with SCP and SFTP, let me try this and will update you if it works. Thanks.