# C# - Upload and rename file via SFTP

Tags: c#, sftp

In my C# project I have to implement a method that must transfer a file to sftp and then rename the file.
Is there a C# or a dll free to add that does this?
Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530330/sftp-libraries-for-net

Comment: Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) where it notes "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it."  Also, likely duplicate of [How do I upload a file to an SFTP server in C# / .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/86458/150605).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WinSCP .NET Assembly and COM Library wraps the popular WinSCP and is quite flexible.    https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library

Comment: Thanks @Tim
I use SSH.NET ...https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/