# FtpWebRequest - Setting Port 22 in the URI

Tags: .net, vb.net, ftp, sftp, ftpwebrequest

I am trying to upload files in the FTP server I have been using the `FtpWebrequest`. At default, the port is 21. I need to upload using port 22. I have tried adding port 22 in the URI itself. But i get an error while reaching `GetRequestStream()` method. The error message is

> The underlying connection is closed. The server committed a protocol violation

My code looks like below

```
Dim request = DirectCast(FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://absd.com:22/inbox/xxx.dat"), FtpWebRequest)
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(userID,pwd)
request.UseBinary = True
request.UsePassive = True
Dim bytes() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(sourceFilePath)
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length
Using uploadstream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    uploadstream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
    uploadstream.Close()
End Using
```

Let me know what have I missed.

Answer (score 2):

Port 22 is for SSH/SFTP. That's not FTP. So you cannot use `FtpWebRequest`.

There's no SFTP implementation in .NET. You have to use a 3rd party library.

See also:

- [How do I upload a file to an SFTP server in C# / .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/86458/850848)
- [SFTP Libraries for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/530330/850848).